# Play soundtrack in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, playsound

I make a game in C++ without using any engine. And now I want to play sound track in my game. I use function Playsound to play my sound track but when I get a score, it'll have another sound comes up and turns off my sound track.

I want to use SND_MEMORY but I don't know how to use it and it doesn't work.

Can you help me? If you have another way, please say it, I'm sure it will help me.

Thank you.

Comment: You can't play multiple sounds at a time with `PlaySound()`. There are multiple higher level multimedia APIs available in Windows which offer much more functionality, including playing multiple sounds at a time. You need to rethink your approach.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [XAudio2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/xaudio2/xaudio2-introduction).

Comment: [MciSendString function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd757161(v=vs.85)) might be a way, too.